# if statement with 3 "and" (&&) operators causes error when rearranged

Tags: java, operators

Can someone explain to me why when I rearrange the conditions in the following if statement it either throws a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException or it does not;

```
public int matchUp(String[] a, String[] b) {
int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i].length() > 0 && b[i].length() > 0 &&
      a[i].charAt(0) == b[i].charAt(0)) {
      count++;
  }
}
   return count;
}
```

Basically my question is, how is this if statement

```
if (a[i].charAt(0) == b[i].charAt(0) &&
    a[i].length() > 0 && b[i].length() > 0)
```

different from this if statement

```
if (a[i].length() > 0 && b[i].length() > 0 &&
    a[i].charAt(0) == b[i].charAt(0)) {
      count++;
}
```

The first one throws an exception, for example:

```
matchUp(["", "", "ccc"], ["aa", "bb", "cc"]) → 1
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0 (line number:6)
```

Comment: How can you be sure that length of `a` is equal or greater than length of `b`?

Comment: it is stated in the problem description

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0 (line number:6)
```

means that you tried to access index 0 of an array which is empty.

Another thing is, that expression `expression1 && expression2` is evaluated to false when only `expression1` is false. There is no attempt to evaluate expression2.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't really allude to how the order of the operands matter when `&&` is evaluated.